# Given a correlation matrix and sample size, how to calculate which correlation coefficients are statistically significant?

Tags: correlation, p-value, sample-size

Suppose you are given a correlation matrix and a sample size. How do you calculate which correlation coefficients are statistically significant?

If there are $K$ variables then there are $K^{2}$ entries in the correlation matrix, of which $K$ are on the diagonal. Half of the entries are the same, so there are $\displaystyle\frac{K^{2} - K}{2}$ correlation coefficients. Assuming the Bonferroni correction, the critical value $\alpha = 0.05$ would be divided by that number.

However, how do I obtain the P values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain $p$-values for Pearsons correlation using Student's $t$-distribution, since

$$ t = r \sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2} } $$

has $t$-distribution (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution) for learning more and further references).